# CropOverlayView being reset on setImageBitmap

Tags: java, android, imageview, crop

I am using the edmodo cropper library for android, i am having a problem with updating the CropOverlayView (on top of the imageview where you select which part to crop), once I call mCropImageView.setImageBitmap() and set the mCropImageView “Edges”, the mCropImageView doesnt seem to reflect the “Edges” changes I made?

```
 mUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.view_update);
 mUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override 
 public void onClick(View view) {
 File f = new File(Url);
 Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));

 if (mCropImageView != null) {
 mCropImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
 Edge.LEFT.setCoordinate(400);
 mCropImageView.invalidate();
 }
});
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/edmodo/cropper/wiki

Comment: What was the problem. How did you solve it?